# "More an X" vs. "More of an X"?

Tags: prepositions, nouns, comparative

Are the following sentences grammatical?

> a. He is more a poet than a novelist in the traditional sense.
>
> b. They are more poets than novelists in the traditional sense.
>
> c. He is more of a poet than a novelist in the traditional sense.

The question is whether the 'of' is necessary.

Comment: I think it is clear that this was not a request for proofreading.  Those three sentences are all idiomatic and have the same basic meaning, taking into account the difference between the singular and the plural, of course.  **more a poet** and **more of a poet** are both OK.  Some style guides may discourage the latter but it comes out of the mouths of tens of millions of native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference is mostly spoken versus written English.

> a. He is more a poet than a novelist in the traditional sense.

is acceptable when spoken.

While:

> c. He is more of a poet than a novelist in the traditional sense.

is preferred when in writing.